# How to store the timezone?

Tags: php

Hi i am using PHP to store the timezone.The timezone coming from dropdown and when I try to store it if its **(GMT+5.30) or (GMT+anything) the plus symbol doesnt stored on database**.It **stored as (GMT 5.30).**How can I store it correctly?

Comment: Please give more information. In which database you're unable to store this information. What kind (type) of column did you use?

Comment: Could it be an encoding issue? "+" is interpreted as space in (most) url encoding(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$url_safe = urlencode($string);

Comment: Your answer is good.Is there anyother way to store without encryption.

Comment: can u post the insert string, so that i could check what went wrong with your sql code.

Answer (score 1):

Store all your times in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), that way you can easily convert them to any timezone that you require.

As for the timezone - I would store this in a seperate column either with the offset from [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) or even better store the locale of the timezone e.g. "America/New_York" that way you can accomodate for daylight saving times also.